# How to add woocommerce variable product to two price with difference currency

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm beginner for the WordPress. Any one know How to display woocommerce variable product to add two price option with using  difference currency,
Thanks

**example**

Kelloggs Corn Flakes - 250 Gr

when i click the price option select Other Country after display  $ 2.5 and when i click the price option select local display $ 0.5, i want to change local currency to my local currency option, both are US Dollar
look localhost sample image
my localhost sample

[image: image 01]

[image]

Comment: Not getting what you want, please give more details about it.

Comment: @PPL , Sir updated

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: hope you have solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin for extra shipping:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-extra-flat-rate/

[image]

Comment: Sir, I dont want to shipping calculate option , i want to add product to difference prices(two price )

Comment: For product different price you can add variable product. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/

Comment: yeah I added Variable Products, its work for me, but cant add  two currency, look my attached image, both of US $

Comment: For that you can add plugin also.

Comment: sir, you know the name of suitable plugin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171062/discussion-between-ppl-and-core114).

Comment: Plugin name: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-price-based-on-countries/

Comment: let's continue chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171062/discussion-between-ppl-and-core114

Comment: ,Please update your answer , current answer is not my solution.